# Outlook 2010 Rule: Move message if greater than 5 recipients

Tags: vba, outlook-2010

The only time I get emails with 5+ recipients is when the office gossip is going around. I would love to make a rule/filter to move any incoming message with more than 5 recipients into a junk folder.

Is that possible with Outlook 2010? I could not find anything like that in the default rules, wasn't sure if you could VBA the rule via Macro or something.

Any insight, help, or resources are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the VBA script using the resources DeanOC provided if anyone is interested.

This script takes all incoming emails and counts the recipients in the `To:` field,if recipient count is greater than 5, marks it as read, and moves is to a `Gossip` folder.

There is also a secondary condition to check if subject contains `CVS` (we get updates from our concurrent version system which has 10 recipients) and move is to the appropriate folder.

```
Sub moveOfficeGossip(item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim strNames As String, i As Integer, j As Integer, cvs As String
    Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    j = 1
    cvs = "CVS"
    strNames = item.To
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    For i = 1 To Len(strNames)
        If Mid(strNames, i, 1) = ";" Then j = j + 1
    Next i

    If (j >= 5) Then
        If InStr(UCase(item.subject), cvs) Then
            Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Filtered").Folders("CVS")
            item.Move olDestFolder
        Else
            Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Filtered").Folders("Gossip")
            item.UnRead = False
            item.Move olDestFolder
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I apologize if this is not in the most formal format and I know that it can be organized a bit better, but this was my first attempt at using any Visual Basic syntax.

Answer (score 3):

This link: [How to replace text in the body of an incoming message with a hyperlink in Outlook 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/464000/how-to-replace-text-in-the-body-of-an-incoming-message-with-a-hyperlink-in-outlo) shows how to create a custom action when using the "after message arrives" condition. You would need to change the VBA code to interrogate your mailitem to see if it has 5+ recipients and then move the mailitem to your junk folder.

The recipients can be found by looking at the `MailItem.To` property (a semi-colon delimited string)

If the message meets your criteria then you can use the `MailItem.Move` method to move the message to your desired folder.

This link: [MailItem Members (Outlook)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861252%28v=office.14%29.aspx) give more information on the `MailItem` object.

Comment: Thank you for the resources. I'll see what I can come up with.